# How to abort a transiton from Transition.$onstart in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, transition

event.preventDefault used to work with earlier versions but not now.

```
 $transitions.onEnter({
      }, function(trans) {

           //Abort Transition method here.
           if(getDatafromServer())
            {  $state.go('register');
            }
           else
          {
           $state.go('login');
         }
        }
```